# Google G Suite SAML SSO domain login page

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, google-apps, google-account, google-sso

I'm usign Google G Suite and created an app which is manage users logins with G Suite SAML. 
(see. https://support.google.com/a/answer/6087519?hl=en&ref_topic=6304963#)

Everything is works smoothly, but I have problem when users not logged in our G Suite account and also logged in their own Google account.

In that case, Google login page not asks user to login our G Suite account and gives **403 - app_not_configured_for_user** error directly.

So, here is the questions

- What should I do for log-in our users in that case?
- There is any available domain login page in G Suite?
- Or even more perfect, is there any custom login page for SAML login?

Thank you.

Comment: This link looks helpful: https://robinpowered.com/blog/how-to-set-up-saml-with-google-apps/
You have to allow the app for every user, which is done in the "SAML applications" section of the G-Suite admin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paul, but I already enabled my app for every user on my G-Suite. If user is only logged in our G-Suite account there isn't any problem. 
But, if user is logged an other account, Google login page does not ask for account chose and gives error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @MakkyNZ unfortunately I did not found.

Comment: I found a fair solution , redirect the browser to :

https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue= {url encoded current redirection url}

Its based on post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806629/google-saml-app-not-configured-for-user-equivalent-of-prompt-select-account-sa

Comment: This post was created five years ago and still no answer. I'm really curious whether the bountry actually causes this question to be answered.

Comment: I am facing the same issue (Only one account it signed in others signout out including IDP domain) We have keycloak as service provider and using google IDP (saml2 app). Would like to know solution or work around to forcefully enable Acount Chooser using keycloak config ?
I do I force choose account in above configuration

Answer (score -2):

Instead of redirecting the user from your application to the Google Identity Provider, try redirecting them to the Google Account Chooser, which is:

https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser?continue=

**Credits to Neal Soni:
[Google SAML app_not_configured_for_user / equivalent of prompt=select_account SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806629/google-saml-app-not-configured-for-user-equivalent-of-prompt-select-account-sa)

https://stackoverflow.com/users/12413808/neal-soni**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).