# Google SAML app_not_configured_for_user / equivalent of prompt=select_account SAML

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, http-status-code-403, google-oauth, google-workspace

I'm using Gsuite as an Saml IDP to authentify users of my organisation on internal apps.

Everything is working fine, except for one point:
when one of my users if logged in with his/her personal account **only**, Google will fail with:

> 403 Error: app_not_configured_for_user

This makes sense as the app is intended to be used by internal users only, but I would like to be able to force Google saml authentication to display the account selector even if the user is already logged in to one account [as this is possible for oauth2 with prompt=select_account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect).

Any way to have the same behavior with SAML ?

---

[EDIT] I actually managed to achieve what I want by using

> https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser/?continue=$SAML_REQUEST$

---

[EDIT 2] Here is the code snippet for the adaptation in ruby on rails (using [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml))

*config/initializers/saml_override.rb*

```
module OneLogin
  module RubySaml
    class Authrequest < SamlMessage
      GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CHOOSER_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue="
      alias_method :old_create, :create
      def create(settings, params = {})
        self.old_create(settings, params)
        @login_url = GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_CHOOSER_URL + CGI.escape(@login_url)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, interested in your solution. I can't seem to force Google to show the AccountChooser. Using PHP with php-saml library. Thanks.

Comment: @gregjor I added the details for ruby you could adapt for php

Comment: Thanks but that URL is not working for me, even from the command line with curl.

Comment: I am facing the same issue (Only one account it signed in others signout out including IDP domain) We have keycloak as service provider and using google IDP (saml2 app). Would like to know solution or work around to forcefully enable Acount Chooser using keycloak config ?
I do I force choose account in above configuration

Answer (score 7):

Good that you've resolved your problem. I thought I'd add a few archirectural points.

**SAML**

`ForceAuthn` is a [SAML Attribute](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-request-initiation-cd-01.html) that you can send in an authentication request. There are  others such as `EntityId` for apps that need to control which login method should be used.

**OPENID CONNECT**

This has better options I would say, as a more up to date standard. The JOSE based technologies work well for web and mobile clients, in pretty much any tech stack.

There are a greater number of [request parameters](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) such as `acr_values` to replace EntityId, and `prompt` has more options than ForceAuthn, as you pointed out. This also provides additional session management options as in [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023179/re-authentication-using-identity-server-4/71050973#71050973).

**PROVIDERS**

Not all providers are standards based, and sone may not support ForceAuthn, prompt, acr_values etc, but you may still want to use them for login purposes. To solve your problem you had to resort to a non SAML Google specific request parameter. The more login providers you use, the worse this gets - and application complexity grows.

**OPTIMAL ARCHITECTURE**

For future reference, it is worth aiming for this architecture, in case any of this is new to you:

- Application code only uses OpenID Connect, which is a much larger space than many people are aware of - have a look at [this summary of standards](https://curity.io/resources/learn/openid-connect-standards/).
- Apps only redirect to an Authorization Server, which in turn manages connections to [identity providers](https://curity.io/product/authentication-service/ways-to-authenticate/) and their peculiarities. These connections can use SAML, OIDC or anything else needed.
- The end result should be simple and portable code in apps, which also have support for the most cutting edge authentication flows.

At least that's sonething I like to aim for - identity remains a challenge, sometimes with too many annoyances :).

Answer (score 2):

```
class SamlController < ApplicationController

  def init
    request = OneLogin::RubySaml::Authrequest.new
    redirect = request.create(saml_settings)

    # google doesn't support ForceAuthn so we have to redirect requests to the account chooser first
    google_account_url_chooser = "https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?continue="
    if redirect.include?("https://accounts.google.com")
      encoded_redirect = CGI.escape(redirect)
      redirect = "#{google_account_url_chooser}#{encoded_redirect}"
    end

    redirect_to(redirect)
  end

  def saml_settings 
    ...
  end
end
```