# Google SAML SSO - 403 app_not_configured_for_user error when signed into personal Google account

Tags: google-api, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, google-sso

I'm working on a SAML SSO integration for our app using Google / G Suite. Our customers configure our SAML app in their company's G Suite admin settings. The integration works correctly in most cases:

- Suppose you're not signed into a Google account yet. You initiate the SSO process. You're prompted to sign into your company Google account, and SSO works correctly.

[image: google account prompt when not signed in yet]

- Suppose you're already signed into your company Google account *and* your personal Google account. You initiate the SSO process. You see an account chooser. If you choose your company Google account, SSO works correctly.
  [image: account chooser prompt when signed into multiple accounts]

**However, SSO fails in this case:**

- Suppose you are only signed into your personal Google account. Google does not display the account chooser. Instead, you immediately get a a 403 error: "Error: app_not_configured_for_user."

[image: 403 error if only signed into wrong account]

This has led to a very confusing experience for our users. It's pretty common that you're currently only signed into one google account that's not your company google account. Furthermore, the error page is opaque -- it's not clear to a user what they did wrong.

Is there any way to always show the account chooser? For example, are there any parameters we can add to the `/o/saml2/idp` url or the SAML AuthnRequest? (E.g. we tried setting `ForceAuthn` and adding a `<saml:Subject>` block in the AuthnRequest, but it seems Google's SAML does not support either.)

Or is there a way for our app to get a callback on error, so we can show a more meaningful error message?

(I contacted G Suite support, and they said to ask our question on Stack Overflow instead. Appreciate your help here!)

Comment: Hi Sohan, did you find a workaround for this issue? I am currently having the same issue.

Comment: @NPhillips unfortunately we did not find a workaround. We did not hear back from G Suite Support either. Please let me know if you find a solution here as well!

Comment: Same problem, still no solution

Comment: This only happens when you are logged in to your personal account only... If you have a google's multi-user mode and are already logged in two all accounts, it's not an issue... the option below works best. It's not strictly standards compliant...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337974/google-g-suite-saml-sso-domain-login-page

Comment: I am facing the same issue (Only one account it signed in others signout out including IDP domain)
We have keycloak as service provider and using google IDP (saml2 app). Would like to know solution or work around to forcefully enable Acount Chooser using keycloak config ?

Comment: Four years later and the same issue still persists. I encountered this when I use Canva, the sign in process simply failed (app_not_enabled) without any useful message, if I got logged out from my organization's gmail and left with my personal gmail only. It would be much more helpful if it said "app is not enabled for daniel_wu@gmail.com". Since you are the one making the app, why not switch to Oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of redirecting to directly from your app to the Google IDP, you need to redirect to 
https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser?continue={theredirectURL}

See
[Google SAML app_not_configured_for_user / equivalent of prompt=select_account SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806629/google-saml-app-not-configured-for-user-equivalent-of-prompt-select-account-sa)

Comment: Doing that gives me `null. That’s an error., Error parsing the request, No SAML message present in request That’s all we know.` My url looks like this https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

if you using a `passport-saml`
[There is a fork that fixes this behavior.](https://github.com/DmtrPn/passport-saml)
Set in configuration `googleAuth: true` and then during authorization there will be a redirect to the google account selection page

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue. When I then added the G suite account to my Android device under Settings > Accounts and retried the login flow, I was properly prompted with the Account Chooser. Not the solution I was really looking for, but it did change the outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do this:

1. In the same browser window where you get the error, click the Google icon.
2. You are likely either not signed in **that** browser, or using a different account. Sign out using the sign out button.
3. Sign in with the correct SAML enabled Google account in that browser.
4. Go back to the original app which opened that browser window and retry the authentication. It should now work as the browser is pre-authenticated with the right account.
5. Afterwards you can logout that account from that browser and/or swap back to the other one it was using before.

In summary, the error message is valid: it was trying to login with another user than the one which had SAML enabled/was to be used.

Answer (score -4):

I had the exact same problem when working with Keeper Password Manager. I solved it by erasing everything from ~/Library/Application Support/Keeper Password Manager/Cookies

I suggest you look for a similar folder in your app and do the same

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you delete your cookies, then you also sign yourself out of all google accounts. This issue in this post only happens when a user is signed into multiple accounts. Ideally there's a server-side solution that google provides that solves the problem for all our customers. Telling our customers to delete their cookies or to sign out of all of their accounts is not the most user-friendly experience unfortunately