# Nextcloud and Google SAML SSO: Error parsing the request, No SAML message present in request

Tags: single-sign-on, google-workspace, nextcloud

I struggle a bit to get Nextcloud to work with Google as SSO provider. I have `URL target of the iPd` is `https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxxx` then I get

```
403. That’s an error.

Error: app_not_configured_for_user
```

So following [the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58223843/google-saml-sso-403-app-not-configured-for-user-error-when-signed-into-persona), I changed the url to

```
https://accounts.google.com/accountchooser?continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/idp?idpid=xxxxxx
```

Which redirects me to the google account chooser, but then I get, after selecting my account

```
null. That’s an error.

Error parsing the request, No SAML message present in request That’s all we know.
```

[image]

Sometimes I am **not asked for a user account**, so then I get the following from Nextcloud

```
Account not provisioned.

Your account is not provisioned, access to this service is thus not possible.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to configure Google having these attribute mappings
[image: google config]
While on Nextcloud I configure SAML as follows
[image: nextcloud saml config]